# Create new variable based on existing columns of a cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pivot-table, cell-array

I have a cell-array with 600 000 rows and 5 columns. In the following example I only present 3 different codes and a period of 5 years. Input:

```
c1   c2        c3        c4  c5 

1   2006    20060425    559 'IA'
1   2007    20070129    559 'LO'
1   2007    20070826    559 'VC'
1   2008    20080825     34 'VP'
1   2009    20090116     34 'ZO'
4   2007    20070725     42 'OI'
4   2008    20080712     42 'TF'
4   2008    20080428     42 'XU'
11  2007    20070730    118 'AM'
11  2008    20080912    118 'HK'
11  2009    20090318      2 'VT'
11  2010    20100121      2 'ZZ'
```

I would like to obtain a new variable that gives for each code (`c1`) the years in which `c1` appears in the sample and the corresponding `c4` value. For instance:

Output:

```
x  2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
1  559  559  34   34   - 
4   -   42   42   -    -
11  -   118  118  2    2
```

To get to my cell-array, this is the code I used so far:

```
a1=T_ANNDAT3;
a2=I{:,7};
a3=I{:,6};
a4=I{:,16};
a5=I{:,1};
TRACK_AN = [num2cell([a2 a1 a4 a3]) a5];
TRACK_AN(cell2mat(TRACK_AN(:,1))==0,:)=[];
[~,indTA,~] = unique(strcat(TRACK_AN(:,1),TRACK_AN(:,2),TRACK_AN(:,4),TRACK_AN(:,5)));
TRACK_AN = TRACK_AN(indTA,:);
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate this very easily using `unique` as what you have seen.   The key is to use the `'rows'` flag as the second parameter into `unique` so you can figure out the unique **row** entries for the matrix.  We only need the first, second and fourth columns of the matrix for this process so we can just subset those columns out.  You also need to use the additional output parameters of `unique` so we can figure out where exactly the unique rows appear in the original cell array.  This is the key property we need for the next part of the algorithm.

After you find the unique cell array from the first `unique` call, we apply `unique` two more times - One for the column of `c1` and one more for the column of `c2` so we can index the ID and the year.  We will use the third output parameter of `unique` so that we can assign each unique number within each column into a unique ID.  We then use `accumarray` to create the final matrix that you see above, binning the values in the fourth column given the first column serving as rows and the second column serving as columns for this final matrix.  In other words:

```
%// Create cell array as per your example
C = {1   2006    20060425    559 'IA'
1   2007    20070129    559 'LO'
1   2007    20070826    559 'VC'
1   2008    20080825     34 'VP'
1   2009    20090116     34 'ZO'
4   2007    20070725     42 'OI'
4   2008    20080712     42 'TF'
4   2008    20080428     42 'XU'
11  2007    20070730    118 'AM'
11  2008    20080912    118 'HK'
11  2009    20090318      2 'VT'
11  2010    20100121      2 'ZZ'};

%// Get only those columns that are relevant
%// These are the first, second and fourth columns
Cmat = unique(cell2mat(C(:,[1 2 4])), 'rows');

%// Bin each of the first and second columns
%// Give them a unique ID per unique number    
[~,~,ind] = unique(Cmat(:,1));
[~,~,ind2] = unique(Cmat(:,2));

%// Use accumarray to create your matrix    
%// Edit - Thanks to Amro
%// Any values that are missing replace with NaN
finalMat = accumarray([ind ind2], Cmat(:,3), [], [], NaN);
```

The output is thus:

```
finalMat =

559   559    34    34   NaN
NaN    42    42   NaN   NaN
NaN   118   118     2     2
```

I replaced those values that were missing with `NaN` to signify the missing values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it helps, and your explantions make it really simple to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @user3557054 - You are most welcome!  I changed some of the wording slightly as I wrote that in a rush and some stuff wasn't clear.  It should be more clear now, but I'm glad it helped. Good luck!

Comment: careful with replacing zeros with NaNs in the last step: if `0` appears in `c4` column, it will be incorrectly replaced..

Comment: @Amro - Very true.  As such, I'll just leave them as 0s then.  I'll modify my post.

Comment: or use the fifth input of `accumarray` to specify the fill-value

Comment: @Amro - Thank you.  I'm modifying my post now.

Comment: @rayryeng: sorry for bugging you, but I think you forgot to remove the last line replacing 0 with NaN, it's no longer needed :) Oh and by the way, since you already applied `unique(..,'rows')` earlier, it doesn't matter whether you use `@sum` or `@max` as the grouping function (you have at most one value per row/column), so you could just specify the default: `accumarray([ind ind2], Cmat(:,3), [], [], NaN)`

Comment: @Amro - Oops!  Yes you're right.  You're also right about the grouping as I used unique.  I can use either `@sum` or `@max` so they'll both behave the same way.  Thank you very much again :)  You're not bugging at all!  I'd give you +10 for your answer to show my gratitude if I could!

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation of @rayryeng's solution:

```
% data as cell array
C = {
    1   2006    20060425    559 'IA'
    1   2007    20070129    559 'LO'
    1   2007    20070826    559 'VC'
    1   2008    20080825     34 'VP'
    1   2009    20090116     34 'ZO'
    4   2007    20070725     42 'OI'
    4   2008    20080712     42 'TF'
    4   2008    20080428     42 'XU'
    11  2007    20070730    118 'AM'
    11  2008    20080912    118 'HK'
    11  2009    20090318      2 'VT'
    11  2010    20100121      2 'ZZ'
};

% we are only interested in three columns
CC = cell2mat(C(:,[1 2 4]));

% unique codes/years and their mapping
[codes,~,codesInd] = unique(CC(:,1));
[years,~,yearsInd] = unique(CC(:,2));

% pivot table
out = accumarray([codesInd yearsInd], CC(:,3), [], @max, NaN)
```

The result as expected:

```
>> out
out =
   559   559    34    34   NaN
   NaN    42    42   NaN   NaN
   NaN   118   118     2     2
```

or pretty-printed as a table:

```
>> t = array2table(out, ...
    'RowNames',cellstr(num2str(codes,'code_%d')), ...
    'VariableNames',cellstr(num2str(years,'year_%d')));

>> t
t = 
               year_2006    year_2007    year_2008    year_2009    year_2010
               _________    _________    _________    _________    _________
    code_1     559          559           34           34          NaN      
    code_4     NaN           42           42          NaN          NaN      
    code_11    NaN          118          118            2            2
```

Comment: +1 - I didn't know about `array2table`.  What an awesome prettifying function.

Comment: it's part of the new `table` class and functions introduced in R2013b

Comment: @Amro thank you for your help. I still want to go through all your codes more carefully (to understand better), but it's working.