# Join rows in Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a very big matrix that looks like this:

```
id,value
1,434
2,454353
1,4353
3,3432
3,4323
[...]
```

There can be at most 2 rows with the same id.

I want to reshape the matrix into the following, preferably removing the id's which only appear once:

```
id,value1,value2
1,434,4353
3,3432,4323
[...]
```

Comment: How about something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841586/create-new-variable-based-on-existing-columns-of-a-cell-in-matlab

Comment: Maybe also have a look at `grpstats`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative using [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to identify values sharing the same index. The code is commented and you can have a look at every intermediary output to see what exactly is going on.

```
clear
clc

%// Create matrix with your data
id = [1;2;1;3;3];
value = [434 ;454353;4353;3432;4323];

M = [id value]

%// Find unique indices to build final output.
UniqueIdx = unique(M(:,1),'rows')

%// Find values corresponding to every index. Use cell array to account for different sized outputs.
NewM = accumarray(id,value,[],@(x) {x})

%// Get number of elements 
NumElements = cellfun(@(x) size(x,1),NewM)

%// Discard rows having orphan index.
NewM(NumElements==1) = [];
UniqueIdx(NumElements==1) = [];

%// Build Output.
Results = [UniqueIdx NewM{1} NewM{2}]
```

And the output. I can't use the function `table` to build a nice output but if you do the result looks much nicer :)

```
Results =

           1         434        3432
           3        4353        4323
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does the interesting job of sorting the matrix according to the `id` and removing the orphans.

```
x = sortrows(x,1); % sort x according to index
idx = x(:,1);
idxs = 1:max(idx);
rm = idxs(hist(idx, idxs) == 1); %find orphans
x( ismember(x(:,1),rm), : ) = [] %remove orphans
```

This last part then just shapes the array the way you want it

```
y = reshape(x', 4, []);
y( 3, : ) = [];
y=y';
```